# Abrir link em nova janela

Tags: asp.net, link

Como faço para abrir determinado link, por exemplo `www.google.com` em uma nova janela sem afetar a que estou usando?
Eu vou receber esse link quando executar um método de um WS ele vem em formato string, então tenho que abri-lo para o usuário automaticamente sem a ação dele.

Comment: foi mal, ja tentou isso
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493901/how-to-open-a-page-in-new-tab-on-button-click-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assim que você receber a resposta pode chamar esse método passando a url:

```
function openInNewTab(url){
  window.open(url,'_newtab');
}
```